# UITextField is not clickable/Touchable

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, xamarin, uitextfield

I have two UITextfields in a CustomView in my project, but they are not clickable/touchable. I cannot tap on any of the text fields. Although the textfields can be selected on the tab button of the keyboard in simulator environment. But when I use the mouse to click on the textfield in simulator it won't become the first responder. Any Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Some code of what you've already tried would be great to debug your issue.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITextField.html

Comment: do you have an object over them that gets the touch instead ?

Comment: Could you upload any code or screenshot? It would really help

Comment: This is a silly thing to check but I still fall victim to it when running in the simulator from time to time... make sure that the simulator's keyboard is enabled by toggling CMD-K (or from the taskbar -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

You can check 'user interaction enabled' checkbox on xcode attribute inspector panel, maybe problem is that.

> 1- click on textField,
>
> 2- choose attribute inspector in left panel,
>
> 3- find "view" section,
>
> 4- and check "user interaction enabled"

Or try this code in swift:

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

in Objective-C:

```
textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: I am adding UITextField by code in a custom UIView. By default textfield should be user interaction enabled. :)

Comment: hımmm.. that's right : ) i'll searching for you this situation, if you find something pls add a comment.

Comment: I doubt that there is some transparent view over the textfield, is there any possible way to check the view by touching the view, i mean uitouches.

Comment: ASAD, you can use View Debugging functionality of the XCode to make sure that no views are overlapping your textfields.